# Django multi table on same model

Tags: django, django-queryset, multiple-tables

I have huge table that needed to be sliced into some smaller table, ex:
campaign_01, campaign_02, ...
While using django queryset with different table name for same model, what I only know to set table name on a model is:
Model._meta.db_table = 'tableXXX'

However this method doesn't work in single shell/request. (only work for first time, but not for the next) -> maybe because it still on same instance?
After the second time we tried to set _meta.db_table = 'tableYYY', it will occur an error "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "tableXXX""

I also have tried some suggestion I read for this problem answer like:

```
class ListingManager(models.Manager):
    def get_custom_obj(self, table_name):
        self.model._meta.db_table = table_name
        return self

class ObjectName(models.Model):
    objects = ListingManager()
```

Try to create an Object manager to get new object, but it not work, it still throw same error as before (on the second time setting _meta.db_table)

The only way to make it work if we want to set multiple times for _meta.db_table is we need to exit() the shell first, then re-enter the shell mode (which means for loop is not gonna work).

I know it can be achieved with raw query 'Insert into tableXXX values ()', but any method to do it using django queryset? Thanks~

Comment: Why do you need to split the model? If it's for organization, just break your fields up into chunks and split them up with white space.

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating a wrapper model.

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    # fields...
    name = ...
    age = ...
class Model2(models.Model):
    # fields...
    height = ...
    weight = ...
class ModelAll(models.Model):
    model1 = models.OneToOneField(Model1)
    model2 = models.OneToOneField(Model2)
```

But if you're only doing this for organization, just break the fields up with white space.

This will result in the following tables:

Model1

```
 id | name  | age
------------------
  1 | "Joe" | 21
```

Model2

```
 id | height | weight
----------------------
  1 |  5.85  |  175
  2 |  6.0   |  210
```

ModelAll

```
 id | model1_id | model2_id
----------------------------
  1 |     1     |      2
```

To access sub model fields:

```
modelall = ModelAll.objects.get(...)
modelall_name = modelall.model1.name
modelall_height = modelall.model2.height
```

Comment: In this case the ModelAll will still very huge. The reason why I need to split the table is to decrease the table amount, since it will be very huge amount if put it together. When split the table into some small tables, it might be very easy to do the backup and table migration.

Comment: ModelAll will actually be quite small. Model1 and Model2 will contain columns corresponding to their section. so if Model1 has name and age and Model2 has height and weight for fields, each will be a table that contains ONLY those columns.

ModelAll will only contain 2 fields... an integer that is a foreignkey to Model1 and an integer that is a foreignkey to Model2. It won't contain the individual fields in each model.

Comment: What I'm trying to split is those small table will exactly has the same field for each, ex: AllTable has field "id,name,age,category", then I want to split it into SmallTableCategory1, its field is "id,name,age", then SmallTableCategory2, its field is "id,name,age". In this case those smalltablecategoryX will much smaller than AllTable.

Comment: yes. that's what this does. So replace ModelAll with Person, Model1 with Category_Common, and Model2 with Category_Size. Person is made up of multiple categories of fields. each sub-Model (Model1 and Model2 in this case) contains the group of fields but ModelAll pulls them all together.